IR2110 |VB-VS| value too low
I am trying to build an ESC for a BLDC
After some iteration, I ended up with this schema that uses IR2110
(*3 for each pole of the BLDC):

I think my schema is correct when following the datasheet recommandations. Nevertheless when measuring |VB-VS|, I only have ~5V (instead of min 10V as recommanded).
Is something wrong on my schema ?
In the current situation I am facing:
VDD: 12V          
HIN: 0V
SD: 0V (to GND)
LIN: 5V
VSS: 0V

LO: 0V
COM: 0V (to GND)
VCC: 12V
VS: ~9V
VB: 12V
HO: ~9V

I feel like my problem comes from VB-VS, but Im not so sure...
I have tried use ~1µF bootstrap capacitor, but |VB-VS| stays the same
Thank you for your help :pray:

The bootstrap can only work when U6 is present and the output is switching continously, are you doing that?

R2 and R5 are not needed ... HIN must be a PWM at some rate (> 5 kHz).

I have tried with U6&U13 wired. I've replaced the BLDC with leds for debugging. This implies that nothing will rotate, hence nothing will update the switching :smile:
I do have bldc hall effect sensors wired, so I was expecting to see leds switch when manually rotating the bldc; but VB-VS stays ~9V, and HO/LO don't change.
I am not sure though that PWM rate is above >5kHz... I've not seen that info on datasheet...Don't that prevent motor to "calmely" start rotating ?

If you read the datasheet, you will see Fig 28 and next ... where the frequency is cited (from 100 Hz to 1 MHz) ... But 5 kHz min should be ok.
